# How to create a non-trainable variable in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Does it exist a parameter that specifies a `tf.Variable` as non-trainable, so that the variable is not included in `tf.trainable_variables()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can mark variables as "non-trainable" on [definition](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable):

```
v = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), trainable=False)
```

From the linked documentation (circa TensorFlow v0.11):

> trainable: If True, the default, also adds the variable to the graph collection GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES. This collection is used as the default list of variables to use by the Optimizer classes.

There are also ways to change this condition with APIs such as [tf.get_variable([v])](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#get_variable).

Comment: Can we train input data? like I want to do the opposite of this thing on the input dataset

Answer (score 6):

You can create non-trainable variables in two different ways:

- [`tf.Variable(a, trainable=False)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#__init__)
- [`tf.get_variable("a", a, trainable=False)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable#tfget_variable_1)

There is no easy way to change the variable from trainable to non-trainable and otherwise. Also there is no easy way to check whether the variable is trainable (you need to check whether the name of your variable is in the list of `tf.trainable_variables()`

Comment: I am loading a pre-trained graph from "object detection zoo" but when I run tf.trainable_variables() I get an empty list - what does this mean? what do i do wrong?

Comment: @Jenny Did you figure out why there are no trainable variables in the object detection zoo models ?